# Android. CalendarView...show only one month calendar at a time

Tags: android, calendarview

i am using CalendarView in which i want to view only one month calendar at a time and view next month on scroll but CalendarView shows all the month at a time. 
below is my code.

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:shownWeekCount="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

to be frank I didn't find any specific method to do the same.. But you can do it other way round by setting the layout Height to roughly 200dp to 300dp.

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```

and if you want to limit your calendar to present date here is the code

```
CalendarView calendarview;
calendarView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
 long a = calendarView.getDate();
    calendarView.setMaxDate(a);
```

Comment: yeah limiting height is a solution but I still want the Calendar View to take up the whole parent's size so i can attach events on it. Have you found a work around?

Comment: Maybe you'd know how to solve this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885408/show-only-a-single-month-in-a-calenderview-with-navigation-between-other-months

Answer (score 0):

```
//get month and get how many days in current month
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.setMaxDate(daysInMonth);
```

Comment: Maybe you'd know how to solve this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885408/show-only-a-single-month-in-a-calenderview-with-navigation-between-other-months