# Show only a single month in a CalenderView with navigation between other months

Tags: android

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Android. CalendarView...show only one month calendar at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810905/android-calendarview-show-only-one-month-calendar-at-a-time)

I am creating a layout for a fragment which contains a `CalenderView`

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

The problem is that in the design view, the `CalenderView` seems just like I want it - showing a single month with navigation arrows at the top to the left and right of the month's name to navigate between the month. However, in the device itself, the `CalenderView` is just a very long list of months.. like it took the months and just exploded the list to appear on the entire screen.

How can I limit it to only 1 month and also have the option to navigate through the months?

Limiting the height "kinda" works since it does limit the list, but there still won't be navigational buttons, and setting a constant height is something I prefer not doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar febFirst=Calendar.getInstance();
febFirst.set(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
calendar.setMinDate(febFirst.getTimeInMillis());
Calendar febLast=Calendar.getInstance();
febLast.set(2017, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
calendar.setMaxDate(febLast.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.setDate(febFirst.getTimeInMillis());
```

where calendar is the CalendarView.
[image]

Comment: That's not a good solution since it limits me to a single month with no navigation options. I want it to look exactly like it looks when you add it to the layout with the navigation buttons on top, which let the user switch the months forward or backward

Comment: Ok friend, then use very good and easy analog https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview